# Splash Screen with Download Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So I'm stuck by getting a progress bar as a splash screen while downloading 2 xml files from the Internet.

So far so good, everything works fine for me - but at this point I don't know how to proceed. My Goal is let the User "wait" on a Splash Screen until the App is done with the Download.

I tried passing the int "lenghtOfFile" from the class to my Main Activity. It doesn't work out for me in any way. Also basing my Progress Bar on the Thread seems not the right way when Downloading stuff.

So now I'm thinking of putting the Downloader as a AsyncTask at the End of my MainActivity - but for 2 separate files, is there any classy way to do the downloading twice? And afterwards, is it tricky to get one Progress Bar which goes from 0 -100 instead of two Bars counting each from 0-100?

*** UPDATE

Ok I got my Splash Screen and my TextView which is updated after the first File was downloaded.
So, how can I now get a second download in less as possible code? Can I use any "while" or something to do this?

Is it correct how I implemented the splashTread.start(); on onPostExecute()? I want my Splash Screen to quit after the downloading is complete

Optional: Can I update my TextView with a Download Status from 0 - 100%?

public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

```
final String urlone = config.DL_DJ;

public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}


public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

}
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Thread splashTread;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    TextView splashstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spstatus);

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        splashstatus.setText("ONLINE");
    } else
    {
        splashstatus.setText("OFFLINE");
    }
    new MyTask().execute();
    StartAnimations();
}
private void StartAnimations() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                Splashscreen.this.finish();
            }   finally {
                Splashscreen.this.finish();
            }

        }
    };


}


private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(urlone);

            URLConnection ucon = url1.openConnection();
            int lenghtOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Log.i("SPLASH LOGGER", "Got InputStream and BufferedInputStream");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Events.xml"),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Log.i("SPLASH LOGGER", "Got FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream");


            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            //long total = 0;
            int count;
            //loop and read the current chunk
            while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {

                //keep track of size for progress.
                //total += count;
                //write this chunk
                bos.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            //Have to call flush or the  file can get corrupted.
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();



        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        TextView splashstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spstatus);
    splashstatus.setText("Done Downloading");
    splashTread.start();
  }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {TextView splashstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spstatus);
        splashstatus.setText("Start Downloading");
    }



}



}
```

:: LOGCAT ::

```
 08-17 22:15:23.154 32443-32505/? I/SPLASH LOGGER: Got InputStream and BufferedInputStream
08-17 22:15:23.154 32443-32505/? I/SPLASH LOGGER: Got FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream
08-17 22:15:23.155 32443-32505/? I/URL LOGGER: LINK HERE
08-17 22:15:23.156 32443-32505/? I/URL LOGGER: Events.xml
08-17 22:15:23.157 32443-32505/? I/URL LOGGER: 3
08-17 22:15:23.157 32443-32505/? I/progress: 33.333336
08-17 22:15:23.158 32443-32443/? I/String.valueOf values: 37.37226
08-17 22:15:23.158 32443-32443/? I/String.valueOf values: 74.74452
08-17 22:15:23.158 32443-32443/? I/String.valueOf values: 100.0
08-17 22:15:23.162 32443-32505/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-17 22:15:23.162 32443-32505/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-17 22:15:23.170 32761-32761/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1386 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:656 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:656 com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenu.AssistantMenuReceiver.onReceive:144 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3309 
08-17 22:15:23.329 29472-29472/? I/oneconnect[1.6.03-45_2]: FeatureUtil.isQcSupportedMode - user: 0
08-17 22:15:23.336 29253-29253/? I/ThemeManagerReceiver: ThemeManagerReceiver onReceive android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
08-17 22:15:23.347 32443-32505/? I/SPLASH LOGGER: Got InputStream and BufferedInputStream
08-17 22:15:23.347 32443-32505/? I/SPLASH LOGGER: Got FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream
08-17 22:15:23.348 32443-32505/? I/URL LOGGER: LINK HERE
08-17 22:15:23.349 32443-32505/? I/URL LOGGER:  overall.xml
08-17 22:15:23.349 32443-32505/? I/URL LOGGER: 3
08-17 22:15:23.349 32443-32505/? I/progress: 66.66667
08-17 22:15:23.350 32443-32505/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-17 22:15:23.351 32443-32505/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
08-17 22:15:23.353 32443-32443/? I/String.valueOf values: -68233.33
08-17 22:15:23.354 32443-32443/? I/String.valueOf values: -90099.99
08-17 22:15:23.480 32443-32505/? I/SPLASH LOGGER: Got InputStream and BufferedInputStream
08-17 22:15:23.480 32443-32505/? I/SPLASH LOGGER: Got FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream
08-17 22:15:23.482 32443-32443/? I/String.valueOf values: 100.0
```

NOTE, had to edit some values:

```
        @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
        TextView splashstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spstatus);
        splashstatus.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
        Log.i("String.valueOf values", String.valueOf(values[0]));
    }
```

and here the logging going on:

```
                    String urlStr = urls.keyAt(i);
                Log.i("URL LOGGER",urls.keyAt(i));
                OutputStream file = openFileOutput(urls.valueAt(i),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Log.i("URL LOGGER",urls.valueAt(i));
                float fPercent = (((float)i)/urls.size())*100.0f;
                Log.i("URL LOGGER", String.valueOf(urls.size()));
                Log.i("progress", String.valueOf(fPercent));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty loaded question, so I'll try to provide some guidance without writing a ton of code...

Your intuition is right that you should use ASyncTask for this rather than implementing some sort of IPC using Threads. Specifically, you can use a combination of [publishProgress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)) and [onProgressUpdate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)) (which runs on the UI thread) to update a ProgressBar in your view.

You can use the ASyncTask's [onPostExecute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) callback to do something (exit the splashscreen) after the download has finished.

In terms of doing doing both downloads at once, there is no reason you can't just download them both sequentially in the ASyncTask like you do already. How you handle the ProgressBar in this case though is I guess the interesting part. I would probably just have the first 50% of the ProgressBar be the first file and the second half be the second file. I can post some barebones code if you'd like.

UPDATE:

I think the following is a pretty elegant way of handling this. Could easily be extended to more than 2 files. I made some assumptions about the rest of your code, so it will require edits. There could be errors in this, I have not run it, but it should give you an idea where to go:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Float, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ArrayMap<String, String> urls = new ArrayMap<String, String>();
            urls.put(urlone, "Events.xml");
            urls.put(urltwo, "Whatever.xml");
            for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i ++) {
                String urlStr = urls.keyAt(i);
                String file = urls.valueAt(i);
                float fPercent = (((float)i)/urls.size())*100.0f;

                URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                int lengthOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();

                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                Log.i("SPLASH LOGGER", "Got InputStream and BufferedInputStream");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Log.i("SPLASH LOGGER", "Got FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream");


                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                //loop and read the current chunk
                while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
                    //keep track of size for progress.
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(fPercent + (((float)total)/lengthOfFile)*100.0f);
                    bos.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                //Have to call flush or the file can get corrupted.
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
        TextView splashstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spstatus);
        splashstatus.setText(values[0].toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my Question with a new Code. How can I proceed now?

Comment: Please see me edit, hopefully it gives you some guidance :)

Comment: First Correction is changing String file to "OutputStream file = openFileOutput(urls.valueAt(i),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);"

Comment: Ok, what is missing is that the 100% get's set at the End of the AsyncTask. I couldn't manage to get a increase from 0 1 2 3 4 5... ecc. Can you please give me a hint how to do that? Thx in advance!

Comment: Hmmm seems like this code should be doing that. Can you try putting a debugger on the onProgressUpdate callback and see it is being executed. Or put a log statement in there and see if "values[0]" is correct.

Comment: Oh actually, I did find 1 error in my code that may be the cause of this. The math in publishProgress is wrong. Try changing it to:
publishProgress(fPercent + (((float)total)/lengthOfFile)*(100.0f - fPercent));

Comment: It did improve the behavior, but in the end I get a funny negative number, I put a Logcat on the Value - look in my Edit of my Question, otherwise it will get confusing over here