# Android API 23 / 27 for-Loop behavior

Tags: java, android

So I'm having this for-loop with a Downloader here:

** UPDATED the CODE - here you got on PostExecute & Progress for a Status Bar Update

```
ArrayMap<String, String> urls = new ArrayMap<String, String>();


            urls.put(urlone, "first.xml");
            urls.put(urltwo, "second.xml");
            urls.put(urlthree+"?anid=" + androidId,"score.xml");
            for (int i =0; i < urls.size(); i ++) {
              Log.e("Position i=",String.valueOf(i));
              Log.e("urls size",String.valueOf(urls.size()));
                String urlStr = urls.keyAt(i);
              Log.e("current URL keyAt",urls.keyAt(i));
                OutputStream file = openFileOutput(urls.valueAt(i),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              Log.e("file written valueAt",urls.valueAt(i));
                float fPercent = (((float)(i-1))/urls.size())*100.0f;
              Log.e("URL url site", String.valueOf(urls.size()));

                URL url = new URL(urlStr);
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                int lengthOfFile = ucon.getContentLength();

                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                //Log.d("SPLASH LOGGER", "Got InputStream and BufferedInputStream");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
                //Log.d("SPLASH LOGGER", "Got FileOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream");


                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                //loop and read the current chunk
                while ((count = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
                    //keep track of size for progress.
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(fPercent + (((float)total)/lengthOfFile)*(100.0f - fPercent));
                    bos.write(data, 0, count);

                }
                //Have to call flush or the file can get corrupted.
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
            }



        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
        TextView splashstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spstatus);
        if (values[0]>0)
        {
            splashstatus.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
        }

        //Log.i("String.valueOf values", String.valueOf(values[0]));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        TextView splashstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spstatus);
        splashstatus.setText("DONE...");
        splashTread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {TextView splashstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spstatus);
        splashstatus.setText("UPDATING DATA");
    }


}
```

So my problem is the following: When I'm starting this program on Android 7.0 (Api 27) everything works fine, but going down for example on Android 6.x (API 23) the downloader downloads only urltwo and urlthree - first.xml isn't on the phone, while the same code works perfectly on higher versions of android.
I'm out of ideas to solve this problem, is it possible that for api 23 .. i have to start with i=1?

LOG CAT:

```
11-10 16:54:49.583 5075-5121/? E/Position i=: 0
11-10 16:54:49.583 5075-5121/? E/urls size: 3
11-10 16:54:49.583 5075-5121/? E/current URL keyAt: ***URLTHREE***
11-10 16:54:49.583 5075-5121/? E/file written valueAt: score.xml
11-10 16:54:49.584 5075-5121/? E/URL url site: 3
```

LOG CAT on API Level 27 (same code, everything is working)

```
E/Position i=: 0
E/urls size: 3
E/current URL keyAt: ** URL TWO 2 HERE **
E/file written valueAt: second.xml
E/URL url site: 3
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
E/Position i=: 1
E/urls size: 3
E/current URL keyAt: **URL ONE 1 **
E/file written valueAt: first.xml
E/URL url site: 3
E/Position i=: 2
E/urls size: 3
E/current URL keyAt: **URL THREE 3 **
E/file written valueAt: score.xml
E/URL url site: 3
```

Pay attention guys to this Logcat, I didn't change the order when I did copy & paste. It's quit confusing but it works.

Comment: `i <= urls.size()` ?? Its wrong, should be `i<urls.size()`

Comment: oh sry, that's my fault. Was experimenting with the Code and copied the wrong one, edited for the correct Version!

Comment: I recomend insering some strategic debug logs like  urls.size(), i and  urls.valueAt(i) and try to see what is going on.

Comment: if you still need help after that post the results.

Comment: it only gets weirder... added the logcat

Comment: and yes, that's all I get from the Log.. it seems like the for-loop doesn't even run correctly

Comment: Are you sure *urlone* and *urltwo* are different? Sounds like you overwrite one with another - could try swapping the order of them. Could you also update (copy-paste) your code again if made any changes at all (I guess you at least modified Log statements)?

Comment: And I know the IDE would tell you if you exceed max number of characters for the TAG (23), but for sanity check try reducing string "Looper Lenght urls size" by couple of characters - it's strange it does not get printed.

Comment: I triple checked what you said about urlone and urltwo (different). urls size wasn't printed because of Log.d instead of Log.e - here's the Output: "E/urls size: 3" in addition to what's written in my code (I update it now)

Comment: Pay attention,I now did run the Code on Api 27. I also checked the App on a Mobile Phone with Android 6.0. and Android 7.0 - on 6.0 the Download isn't happening, on 7.0 it's working

Comment: Guys, could this be the Problem: "ArrayMap (ArrayMap<K, V> map)" was added in Api Level 23 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap.html) ?

Comment: Nope, Code is working on Android Api Level 19.... Any Ideas?

Comment: In the link you posted you can see that ArrayMap was added in API 19 so that is not the problem.

Comment: Try replacing the `valueOf()` with ArrayMap method `get()`

Comment: Try to replace your for loop with a new 1 that is only logging the values to see what really is inside the ArrayMap like `for (int i=0; i < urls.size(); i++) { log.d("VALUE", get(i))}`

Comment: I created a dummy looper, but not with the get() Method because I couldn't figure out how that works, here is the Output: E/Dummy Looper: 0
E/Dummy Key: **URL TWO**
E/Dummy Value: two.xml
E/Dummy Looper: 1
E/Dummy Key: **URL ONE**
E/Dummy Value: one.xml
E/Dummy Looper: 2
E/Dummy Key: **URL THREE*
E/Dummy Value: score.xml

Comment: Note that the URL 2 is on i=0 and the URL 1 is on i=1, that's not the order how I place them in the Code

Comment: This code is seriously driving me nuts.. is there any other way I could solve this without an Array Map?  This Code is based on this Thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600724/splash-screen-with-download-progress-bar